# Nothing return in prompt when Scraping Product data using BS4 and Request Python3

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

hope you're all doing good. 
I am trying to scrape a specific product from https://footlocker.fr in order to get product's data such as sizes available. The thing is each time i try to run my script nothing returns.
Thank you in advance!

````
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.footlocker.fr/fr/p/jordan-1-mid-bebe-chaussures-69677?v=316161155904'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

name_box = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'fl-product-details--headline'})
size = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'fl-size-316161155904-UE-21'})

for product in zip(name_box,size):
    name,price=product
    name_proper=name.text.strip()
    size_proper=size.text.strip()
    print(name_proper,'-',price_proper)```
````

Answer (score 1):

Okay. So I found a solution, but it is far from ideal. It is for the following link https://www.footlocker.fr/fr/p/jordan-1-mid-bebe-chaussures-69677?v=316160178204. If you look at the resulting html in page.content, you will obviously notice that the size details are not there. If you read through it a bit, you will see a bunch of references to AJAX leading me to believe it is making an AJAX call and pulling the information in, then parsing it. (This is expected behaviour as stock of items can change over time).

There are two ways to get your data.

1. You know the URL you are trying to fetch data from. The value after `v=` is the SKU of the product. For example, if the SKU is 316160178204 you can directly make a request to https://www.footlocker.fr/INTERSHOP/web/FLE/Footlocker-Footlocker_FR-Site/fr_FR/-/EUR/ViewProduct-ProductVariationSelect?BaseSKU=316160178204&InventoryServerity=ProductDetail
2. For each URL you request, you have to locate the following `DIV` with class `f1-load-animation`, then get the `data-ajaxcontent-url` attribute. Now if you get the `data-ajaxcontent-url` attribute which is `https://www.footlocker.fr/INTERSHOP/web/FLE/Footlocker-Footlocker_FR-Site/fr_FR/-/EUR/ViewProduct-ProductVariationSelect?BaseSKU=316160178204&InventoryServerity=ProductDetail`

Now you make a request to this new URL you have, and somewhere in that JSON, you will see values such as

```
<button class=\"fl-product-size--item fl-product-size--item__not-available\" type=\"button\"\n\n>\n<span>20</span>\n</button>
<button class=\"fl-product-size--item\" type=\"button\"\n\ndata-form-field-target=\"SKU\"\ndata-form-field-base-css-name=\"fl-product-size--item\"\ndata-form-field-value=\"316160178204050\"\ndata-form-field-unselect-group\n\ndata-testid=\"fl-size-316160178204-UE-21\"\ndata-product-size-select-item=\"316160178204050\"\n\n>\n<span>21</span>\n</button>
```

You will have to parse this snippet of data (I think you can use BeautifulSoup for it). You can see that it has a class of `f1-product-size--item__not-available` if it is not available, and the size value is in the `span`.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply ! definitely trying this out, but i will surely need selenium to get the job done in order to automate sessions thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

- `name_box` is empty because you search for `<div>` and the element that contains the class `fl-product-details--headline` is a `<h1>`
- `size` is empty because, as @Sri pointed out, there are some AJAX requests that insert that information in the page after the first request